# How to put selection as single(only one row should be selected) in MaterialTable react

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Is there any option for selecting Only one row instead of multiple rows

```
 <MaterialTable
          title={'data'}
          data={data}
          onSelectionChange={(rows) => setSelectedRows(rows)}
          columns={columns}
          isLoading={loading}
          options={{
            showTitle: true, 
            selection: true, 
          }}
    />
```